# Finding the elements in a structure in C language

Tags: c, programming-languages, reverse-engineering, structure

Is it possible to determine the elements(name & datatype) in a structure(C language) in a library ? If yes, how to do it in C language ? If C language does not support it, Is it possible to get the structure elements by other tricks or is there any tool for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. C has no inbuilt reflection-style support.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean find out when you are programming, or dynamically at runtime?

For the former, sure. Just find the .h file which you are including and you will find the struct definition there including all the fields.

For the latter, no, it is not possible. C compiles structs to machine code in such a way that all of this information is lost. For example, if you have a struct `{int x, float y, int z}`, and you have some code which says

```
a = mystruct.y
```

in the machine code, all that will remain is something like finding the pointer to `mystruct`, adding 4 to it (the size of the int), and reading 4 bytes from there, then doing some floating point operations to it. Neither the names nor the types of those struct fields will be accessible at all, and therefore, there is no way to find them out at runtime.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, but how do to find the pointer to mystruct in the machine code ?

Comment: You would need to read the assembly and understand that (a whole different language). But I don't think that's what you mean. Maybe you misunderstood when I said "something like finding the pointer to mystruct". I meant the generated code will know where `mystruct` is (maybe it takes the address off the stack), and then it will perform the necessary arithmetic. But there isn't enough information in there to know the names and types of the fields at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If by "determine the elements of a structure" you mean "get the declaration of that structure type programmatically", then I do not believe that it is possible - at least not portably. Contrary to more modern languages like C++ ot Java, C does not keep type information in a form available to the actual program.

EDIT:

To clarify my comment about it being impossible "portably":

There could very well be some compiler+debugging format combination that would embed the necessary information in the object files that it produces, although I can't say I *know* of one. You could then, hypothetically, have the program open its own executable file and parse the debugging information. But this is a cumbersome and fragile approach, at best...

Why do you need to do something like that?

Comment: I have a structure into which i have been packing the data by an API, but if i try to print the value on console, it is not printing the proper value. So, if i know where exactly inside the structure the data is getting stored, i would be able to print it out and hence trying to find the particular element of the structure.

Comment: @S.Man: Can you update your question with some sample code? Most C APIs that produce structs with variable formats (usually by using unions) also have one or more fields so that you can tell which format each instance conforms to. If the format is not variable, then you should refer to the elements directly,

Comment: According to Wikipedia, C++ RTTI is only available for objects that have at least one virtual method.  This means that C++ does not do RTTI for C style structs.